# R Coxph() warning message and unexpected results

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

So I have data at the individual level like so :

`ageband <- factor(0:5)
 event.true <- c(1487,1863,1038,874,424,12)
 event.false <- c(50997,32216,16723,12224,7990,1928)`

`df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ageband,event.true,event.false))`

Here is the weird part :

`results <- coxph(tsurv ~ ageband0 + ageband1 + ageband2+ ageband3 + ageband4 +ageband5, data = df)`

I get this warning message :

`Warning message:
In fitter(X, Y, strats, offset, init, control, weights = weights,  :
  Loglik converged before variable  1,2,3,4,5,6 ; beta may be infinite.`

and all of the p-values are exactly 1 ...

- ageband0  1
- ageband1  1
- ageband2  1
- ageband3  1
- ageband4  1
- ageband5  1

Which is really weird, because in previous datasets that I had not cleaned, age was always significant ...

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, e.g. `Error in eval(predvar, data, env): object 'tsurv' not found`.

Comment: Ewww. Badness (serious badness)  lurks in the construction: `as.data.frame(cbind( ...` . You should discard any text that suggests this is a good way to make dataframes. And that criticism is going to be followed by a deprecation of using discrete categories for what is undoubtedly a continuous variable.

Comment: ageband was entered improperly in the formula. Also. There’s no ‘tsurv’